# Relative URLs not taking scheme/protocol of parent page?

Tags: html, apache, http, https, proxy

I'm working with a web page, loaded over HTTPS, which contains relative URLs such as:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/styles.css">`

`<script src="/js/script.js">`

However, the browser refuses to load these assets, throwing errors such as:

*Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.example.com/search' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script ...*

---

The unique thing about this page which I suspect might be complicating the matter, is that it's set up as a reverse proxy in Apache:

```
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
    ProxyRequests off
    ProxyPass /search http://10.0.0.50/search
    ProxyPassReverse /search http://10.0.0.50/search
    ...
</VirtualHost>

<Location /search/>
    ProxyPassReverse /search
</Location>
```

Additionally, I have a rewrite rule to redirect all http traffic to https; this doesn't affect the inclination of the browser to load an asset, though:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

---

The HTML of the parent page is delivered entirely in the initial request, with no iframes or redirects involved.

Why doesn't the browser load relative URLs according to the scheme of the parent page?
It doesn't make sense to me if/how the proxy configuration would change this behavior.

Additionally, might I be able to make use of mod_filter to rewrite the URLs in the document served through the proxy?

Any thoughts would be most appreciated!

Comment: Use `//`. Protocol-agnostic.

Comment: Thanks - unfortunately I can't change the HTML being sent.

Comment: Well what do you mean by "working with" then? Do you load it in an iframe?

Comment: Ultimately I'd be loading this page in an iframe, but the issue is independent of that and happens when directly visiting the page.